# Jquery datatables: How to create a nested table data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm trying to create a similar functionality to this one [nested table](https://jsfiddle.net/karlnicholas/2gc3r7vv/) is that I want ,
but each nested table in child row all the same ,how to change the content in nested table is different ?

javascript :

```
 var opinions =  [{"id":47,"name":"E061140","fileName":null,"disposition":null,"summary":null,"title":"Marr. of Eustice","opinionDate":"2015-12-10"},{"id":48,"name":"C070296M","fileName":null,"disposition":null,"summary":null,"title":"P. v. Nilsson","opinionDate":"2015-12-10"},{"id":50,"name":"S209643","fileName":null,"disposition":null,"summary":null,"title":"P. v. Stevens","opinionDate":"2015-12-10"}];
 var sections = [{"code":"code of civil procedure","sectionNumber":{"position":-1,"sectionNumber":"177.5"},"refCount":2,"section":{"part":"Chapter","partNumber":"4","title":"Incidental Powers and Duties of Judicial Officers","codeRange":{"sNumber":{"position":168,"sectionNumber":"177"},"eNumber":{"position":171,"sectionNumber":"179"}},"depth":3}},{"code":"code of civil procedure","sectionNumber":{"position":-1,"sectionNumber":"580"},"refCount":16,"section":{"part":"Chapter","partNumber":"1","title":"Judgment in General","codeRange":{"sNumber":{"position":862,"sectionNumber":"577"},"eNumber":{"position":879,"sectionNumber":"582.5"}},"depth":3}}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row.index()` to find the appropriate row of the parent table and then use that value as a lookup into an array of the child data via the following code fragment:

`data: sections[row.index()]`

Provided you have converted `sections` into an array of arrays:

`var sections = [[{}, {}...], [{},...]];`

I've simplified the sections data to make it easier to understand in the following fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/y0vgen6z/2/

Comment: how to add one more button in each row of the nested table ,when click the button will POST the row data to info.php and view info.php  in popup window ?